# Kentico Navigation Menu Using hierarchical Viewer

Tags: kentico

I am new to Kentico have learnt Most from Documentation but want to make Navigation Menu from scratch using Kentico 12 Portal Engine have tried googling most articles but have not found anything which makes navigation menu from scratch

Any Link help would be appreciated or some Guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bit older [article](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/creating-a-mega-menu-using-hierarchical-transformations) but the idea still applies.

Comment: Thanks i have created Navigation menu using hierarchical and will soon create an article on medium to create hierarchical Navigation bar and will upload it here!!